# Can %* be used to assign values to a list or array in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

`%1` is the first command line parameter, `%2` is the second command line parameter and so on till `%9`.

`%*` refers to all the arguments. Is there any way to assign these values to a list like done in a shell script as mentioned below ?

`argv=("$@")` where `$@` refers to all command line arguments in a shell script.

Comment: This is a windows group. Why post unix code. Post it to Unix. In windows we use the `shift` command. How will you ever get a job if you can't use Windows.

Comment: @Noodles: It's perfectly valid to use a comparison to Unix in order to illustrate the task at hand. What's your problem?

Comment: Why waste Windows people time with other operating systems. How would a windows expert know what toy OSs do?

Comment: Because a good sysadmin has enough general knowledge about both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this? :

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set arg_number=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
    set "args[!arg_number!]=%%a"
    set /a arg_number=arg_number+1
)

echo %args[0]%
echo %args[1]%
echo %args[2]%
```

Comment: Thanks. Whys is this args[!arg_number!]=%%a in quotes?

Comment: The double quotes are not necessary, merely standard practice to prevent the inclusion of hidden characters such as spaces in the varaible value.

Comment: @RRR, just like it is a best practice to put quotes around your file names and file paths because of spaces.  Putting quotes around your SET commands also helps protect your variables content.

Comment: Two problems - 1) this only works as long as no argument contains `*` or `?`. 2) If you put quotes around the assignment, then you must use `%%~a` to strip any existing quotes in parameter, else poison characters are likely to be left unquoted.

Comment: Is there any equivalent variable substitution way for  ${parameter:+word}(as in a shell script) in a batch file?

Comment: Does set /a arg_number=arg_number+1 work actually? I tried incrementing the array index in a similar way but the value of arg_number remains 0 all the time. Why is it so? What would have gone wrong? @Squashman